# How can I reuse objects in django without adding more queries?

Tags: python, django

In the following code every `amount = u.filter(email__icontains=email)` django performs another query for my filter, how can I avoid these queries?

```
u = User.objects.all()  
shares = Share.objects.all()  
for o in shares:
    email = o.email
    type = "CASH"
    amount = u.filter(email__icontains=email).count()
```

Comment: I don't see why you would require using `u`, just use `amount= User.objects.filter(email__icontains= email)`

Comment: What is `shares`? Is it another query? Could you show it?

Comment: I just added the shares, when django calls u.filter then it doesnt use the objects from User.objects.all() rather it calls another query, and every time the loop runs the number of queries increases, please help

Answer (score 5):

This whole piece of code is very inefficient and some more context could help.

- What do you need `u = User.objects.all()` for?
- calling `QuerySet.filter()` triggers a query. By calling `filter()` you just specify some criteria for recordset you want to obtain. How else are you supposed to get the records matching your conditions if not via running a DB query? If you want Django not to run a DB query then you probably dont know what are you doing.
- filtering with `filter(email__icontains=email)` is very inefficient - database cant use any index and your query will be very slow. Cant you just replace that by `filter(email=email)`?
- calling a bunch of queries in a loop is suboptimal.

So again - some context of what are you trying to do would be helpful as someone could find a better solution for your problem.